# Create Landing Page With Login or Subscribe Form

Tags: plugins

I am trying to create a landing page with a subscribe or register/login form that does the following:

- Redirects new users to a different page after registering (or subscribing),
- Redirects returning users to page after login (or after re-entering their email address),
- Automatically subscribes users to my mailchimp rss list.

I am using the plugin [MailChimp for WP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) right now and it redirects new subscribers to a new page but not returning ones. Is there a way I can do this with this plugin?

If not, what plugin(s) can I use to make all of these things happen?

I need to have this landing page finished by Saturday 8/10/13.

Comment: What have you tried already? Also, **please** reformat your question, especially the title. Shouting doesn’t make your question more important.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Contact form plugin and create a form according to your choice. instead of a post keep a registration page on homepage.